# In a subdomain network, what .htaccess settings can I use to have WP ignore requests to one subdomain?

Tags: htaccess, multisite, subdomains

I have a subdomain network installed at, say http://example.com. I need to have my webmail running at http://webmail.example.com. When I go to this domain it redirects to a page for creating a new site: http://example.com/wp-signup.php?new=webmail.

I know there are some entries WP uses in the .htaccess file, but how can I get WP to ignore requests to webmail.example.com? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article: http://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Wildcard_Subdomains_for_multi_site_under_Plesk_Control_Panel

I had used it originally when setting up the wildcard subdomains on my Plesk server. At first I didn't need to worry about the webmail section, but now I do, and here's what I did:

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/conf.d
$ mv zzz_horde_vhost.conf zz001_horde_vhost.conf
$ /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

This way, the Horde config will be loaded before the wildcard subdomains.